# Symfony2 alternative to ZF gotoRouteAndExit

Tags: redirect, symfony, controller

Like in the header, is there any elegant way to perform redirect in Symfony2 Controller forward path without performing further task/generating views?

For now the only function that I've found is `$this->redirect()` but unfortunately program flow continues after invoking it and tries to generate corresponding view.

The only alternative (for now) is

```
$this->redirect();
disableViewRendering(); //dummy function
return;
```

Is there any more elegant way to perform this task?

Thanks.

**EDIT:**
as phpisuber01 stated the right way to use `$this->redirect` is

```
...
return $this->redirect();
...
```

Comment: `return $this->redirect();` should do exactly that.

Comment: Thanks phpisuber, I wasn't aware that i had to use return :S